# Regex to match whole word with a particular definition of a word

Tags: regex

I am doing a file search and replace for occurrences of specific words in perl. I'm not usually much of a perl or regex user. I have searched for other regex questions here but I couldn't find one which was quite right so I'm asking for help. My search and replace currently looks like this:

```
s/originalword/originalword_suffix/g
```

This matches cases of originalword that appear in the middle of another word, which I don't want. In my application of search and replace, a whole word can be defined as having the letters of the latin alphabet in lowercase or capital letters and the digits 0-9 and the symbol _ in any uninterrupted sequence. Anything else besides these characters, including any other symbols or any form of whitespace including line breaks or tabs, indicate operations or separators of some kind so they are outside the word boundaries. How do I modify my search and replace to only match whole words as I've defined them, without matching substrings?

Examples:

in the case that originalword = cat and originalword_suffix = cat_tastic

```
:cat { --> :cat_tastic {
:catalog { --> no change
```

Comment: You mean a "whole word" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the \b anchor to match only on a word boundary:

```
s/\bcat\b/cat_tastic/g
```

Although Perl has a slightly different definition of what a "word" is.  Reading the perlre reference guide a couple of times might help you understand regexps a bit better.

Running perl -pi -e "YOUR_REGEXP" in a terminal and entering in lines of text can help you understand and debug what a particular regexp is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the pointer to the docs, this has gotten me on the right track.

Comment: @TimPotter but why `\b[-|+][0-9]+\b` matche `+10` in `43E+10`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
s/([^0-9a-z_])([0-9a-z_]+)([^0-9a-z_])/$1$2_tastic$3/gi
```

Basically, a non-word character, then a set of word characters, followed by a non-word character.  The $1,$2,$3 represent the captured groups, and you replace $2 with $2_suffix.

Hope that helps, not a perl guy buy pretty regex-savvy.  Note that the above will fail if the word is the very first or very last thing in a string.  Not sure if perl regexen allow the syntax, but if so, fixing the first/last issue could be done with:

```
s/(^|[^0-9a-z_])([0-9a-z_]+)([^0-9a-z_]|$)/$1$2_tastic$3/gi
```

Using ^ and $ to match beginning/end of string.

Answer (score 0):

See the example on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) which explains boundary matchers

```
Enter your regex: \bdog\b
Enter input string to search: The dog plays in the yard.
I found the text "dog" starting at index 4 and ending at index 7.

Enter your regex: \bdog\b
Enter input string to search: The doggie plays in the yard.
No match found.
```