# Excluding a single pattern from a perl search and replace with word boundary matching

Tags: regex, perl

After asking [this perl newbie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329245/regex-to-match-whole-word-with-a-particular-definition-of-a-word), I have a perl newbie follow-up. I have discovered the one case in which using the word boundary fails for the purposes of my application which does this regex search and replace over a set of files:

```
s/\bcat\b/cat_tastic/g
```

Which is that I would also like for -cat to not be a match for replacement, although it is currently a match since the hyphen is considered a word boundary. I have read up on word boundaries but what I've learned is that creating a change to boundary conditions when using \b is non-trivial. How do I exclude "-cat" from being searched and replaced? So the end result is:

```
:cat { --> :cat_tastic {
:catalog { --> no change
-cat { --> no change
```

This doesn't have to be part of the one line search and replace, it can also be a condition previous to the search and replace which controls whether the search and replace is executed, although having it in the search and replace would be most useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a newbie regexp, but it seems like the best fit for your pattern: Use a "negative lookbehind" expression, to say "I want what I match NOT to follow a hyphen:

```
s/(?<!-)\bcat\b/cat_tastic/g
```

Addendum: This does the job, but a more general approach (also portable to languages with less fancy regexps) is to split this kind of problem into two: cat after NOT a hyphen, or cat at the start of a string:

```
s/([^-])\bcat\b|^\bcat\b/\1cat_tastic/g
```

Or better yet:

```
s/([^-]|^)\bcat\b/\1cat_tastic/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "word boundary" in your case *only* occurs with "a-z, A-Z, 0123456789, and the underscore and hyphen" as per your comment, you can use a character class:

```
s/(?<![\w-])cat(?![\w-])/cat_tastic/g
```

Word boundary `\b` occurs where characters matching `\w` does not border to another `\w` character. To add hyphen to that, the simplest way is to use a character class like above.

Comment: Sorry, I should have re-described my original issue more clearly rather than just linking to it. I need the word boundary to be anything other than a-z, A-Z, 0123456789, and the underscore and hyphen. Basically, \b minus hyphen as far as I understand how \b is working.

Comment: @Halle `\b` is not an actual character, it is a zero-width assertion. I think that just adding a character to the negation is a fragile solution, but you would know your data better than me, of course.

Comment: You're right and I understand that it is a zero-width assertion. The problem I'm trying to solve is that \b is ideal for every weird case in my many test cases with the one exception that -cat is being replaced. So if I were to use something other than \b, I'd want it to emit the identical results to \b for every other word boundary, but without changing -cat.

Comment: @Halle Word boundary occurs between `\w` and `\W` characters, so to add hyphen to that, use `[\w-]` as I suggested in my recent edit. You can also use `(?<!-)\b`, but I find this version more concise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the discussion, most helpful.